# If statement variable returning empty

Tags: php

this is a test code i wrote to get a value set for $rectype to insert into a table. problem I'm having is $rectype is returning 0 or empty. the files do exist since I perform a similar is_file check to start the process that leads up to this section of the coding

```
$dirchk1 = "/temp/files/" . $data[0] . ".doc"; // exist
$dirchk2 = "/temp/files/" . $data[1] . ".doc"; // exist

$file_1 = (is_file($dirchk1));
$file_2 = (is_file($dirchk2));

if ($file_1) {
$rectype == ($file_2 ? '3' : '1');
}

echo $rectype . "\n";
```

Comment: you are comparing by '==' while you want to assign by '='

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `==` instead of `=`.

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo:

```
$rectype = ($file_2 ? '3' : '1');
```

Also read something about [operator precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php) to avoid using so many useless parentheses.

Answer (score 2):

You need to do an assignment

```
$rectype = ($file_2 ? '3' : '1');
```

instead of a comparison

```
$rectype == ($file_2 ? '3' : '1');
```

Answer (score 2):

As typed everywhere, you are using a comparison `$expression == $expression` instead of an assignment `$variable = $expression;`.

They didn't tell you that your code, as exposed would drop a `E_NOTICE` saying that `$rectype` is uninitialized.

It is good practice to run your code with `error_reporting(E_ALL)` while debugging, and that will tell you these errors and the line where they are.